# why HttpContext.Current.User Could not be initialized is reurn null

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm using this code for Authentication  mvc .I am login  but `Context.User` is null when trace project show current.user null.
I think `Context.User` Could not be initialized
how sloved this problem

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Context.User == null)
            return;
        var userService = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IUserService>();
        var userStatus =       userService.GetStatus(Context.User.Identity.Name);

        if (userStatus.IsBaned)
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();

        var authCookie = Context.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
        if (authCookie == null || authCookie.Value == "")
            return;

        var authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);


        // retrieve roles from UserData
        if (authTicket == null) return;
        var roles = authTicket.UserData.Split(',');

        if (userStatus.Role != roles[0])
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();

        Context.User = new GenericPrincipal(Context.User.Identity, roles);
    }
   private void SetAuthCookie(string userName, string roleofUser, bool presistantCookie)
    {
        var timeout = presistantCookie ? FormsAuthentication.Timeout.TotalMinutes : 30;

        var now = DateTime.UtcNow.ToLocalTime();
        var expirationTimeSapne = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(timeout);

        var authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
            1,
            userName,
            now,
            now.Add(expirationTimeSapne),
            presistantCookie,
            roleofUser,
            FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath
            );

        var encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);

        var authCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket)
        {
            HttpOnly = true,
            Secure = FormsAuthentication.RequireSSL,
            Path = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath
        };

        if (FormsAuthentication.CookieDomain != null)
        {
            authCookie.Domain = FormsAuthentication.CookieDomain;
        }

        if (presistantCookie)
            authCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(timeout);

        Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);
    }
```

Comment: <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Home/Index" timeout="83200" cookieless="UseCookies" name="labportal"/>
    </authentication>

Comment: In your web.config make sure you have this:` <authentication mode="Forms" />`